# What's the point of more vLAN's than actual ports

Tags: switch, vlan

What is the point of having an 8 port switch with 32 vLAN's?

Isn't every port linked to one and exactly one vLAN? So I can use no more than 8 vLAN's. What do I do with the remaining 24?

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't every port linked to one and exactly one vLAN?

No. Most "VLAN-capable" switches support 802.1Q tagging, where a single port can handle packets belonging to multiple VLANs – each packet gets an extra header indicating its VLAN ID.

One main use of tagged VLANs is to have a "trunk" line between two switches. For example, if you put the first 7 ports in their own VLANs, then the 8th port can carry all of them at once, tagged, to the upstream switch. (If you have *several* switches with VLANs, all connected to a central switch in this way, it could easily add up above 32. Really, I would expect 4094 to be the maximum.)

Similarly, routers can also be connected to trunk ports and treat each tagged VLAN as its own virtual interface. Your switch could connect to a router which manages 100 subnets on 100 VLANs all on a single port – then pass some of them to port 2 (to be distributed into individual Ethernet ports by another switch downstream), some more to port 3 (also to be received by another switch), and so on.

Some other devices can also directly consume tagged VLANs – for example, enterprise Wi-Fi access points can connect to a trunk port so that they could offer multiple SSIDs, each belonging to its own VLAN and giving access to a different network.